# Message protocol for sending multiple strings?

Tags: c++, networking, protocols

I'm making a simple client server chat application. I want to be able to send the person's username and after that their message.

Is there some standardized way I'm unaware of that is better than something like:

```
2:9:11:John Korn:Hello World
```

I'm sending UTF-8 strings.

Thanks

Comment: google protocol buffers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to give [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) a read. Protocol Buffer strings are [UTF-8 encoded](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#scalar) by default.

Answer (score 0):

Consider Thrift

http://thrift.apache.org/

Look this article:

http://stuartsierra.com/2008/07/10/thrift-vs-protocol-buffers